# Failed to trigger javascript from backend

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I just switch from coding in vb to c#, so I've got a lot of things to catch up and please assist me on this 1.

I have a javascript function on aspx page, and I would like trigger the function from backend.

Below is my code at backend.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "closeScript", "showMessage('test')", true);
```

Unfortunately I got an error as below.

```
Error   30  Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer.
```

Please help.

Comment: Obviously as error states you can't use this keyword inside any static member.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from PageLoad method

Comment: Hi Michael. There is no error found when I put the script at PageLoad method. But the javascript function will be triggered at PageLoad, I only need to trigger the function when a button is clicked.

Comment: So place it in the event handler on the page

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "closeScript", "showMessage('test')", true);
```

Comment: Hi Taha, thanks for your kind help. But i got a new error as below.
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.get'

Comment: Can you please quote the whole method here? The object reference missing must be of "this"

Comment: Just remove the keyword static from the method and it should work.